# How to find a Window Handle on ProcessID C#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to find a Process with certain name, see if the Class: CTX WndClass exists, if it does.. do nothing an loop through the check every 30secs.

If it does not, wait 30 secs check to see if it does now, if it doesn't close the Process.

This is what I have so far, but it's telling me it's expecting "}" on line 51 and I don't see why lol.

This is the problem, right before the else:

```
private static void FindMain(int handle)
            {
                // Get the class.
                StringBuilder sbClass = new StringBuilder(256);
                GetClassName(handle, sbClass, sbClass.Capacity);

                if (sbClass.Length == 0)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("ARS.exe"))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
                else
                 FindMain(handle);
            }
        }
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
if (sbClass.Length == 0)
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
     foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("ARS.exe"))
     {
         process.Kill();
     }
}
else
{
     FindMain(handle);
}
```

You're missing some curly braces. An `'else'` sentense belongs to an `'if'` sentence so the curly braces must match.

You should really format your code better with matching braces lined up, then you will avoid such problems.